# Get the indices of an array after sorting

Tags: code-golf, array

Your challenge today is to write a program or function which takes a list `l` and gives the positions in `l` at which each successive element of `l` sorted appears.

In other words, output the index of the smallest value, followed by the index of the second smallest value, etc.

You can assume that the input array will contain only positive integers, and will contain at least one element.

Test cases:

```
Input                  | Output (1-indexed)
[7, 4, 5]              | [2, 3, 1]
[1, 2, 3]              | [1, 2, 3]
[2, 6, 1, 9, 1, 2, 3]  | [3, 5, 1, 6, 7, 2, 4]
[4]                    | [1]
```

When two or more elements with the same value appear, their indices should appear next to each other from smallest to largest.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), fewest bytes wins!

Comment: -1 for a trivial challenge that can be solved with built-ins in common golfing languages, *and* for accepting an answer in less than 24 hours. This was neither a fair challenge, nor an interesting one.

Comment: Well, I get why he accepted an answer within 24 hours, it's impossible to beat.

Comment: @CodyGray I thought downvoting when I saw the 1-2 bytes answer, but actually, I don't think it's a bad challenge for more standard programming languages. Of course, it's not a *hard* challenge, but still, there is definitely some golfing possibilities. Of course, it's unpleasant to see 1-byte built-ins, but I don't think that it's fair to blame the challenge for that.

Comment: I'll just leave [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10127/how-can-we-help-users-who-are-put-off-by-the-use-of-golfing-languages) here. Lots of good suggestions in there; [this one](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10140/58518) is especially relevant.

Comment: Using a 1 character builtin is hardly practice. Easy doesn't necessarily mean solvable using only builtins.

Comment: I mean, let's just suppose for the sake of argument that a 1-character answer using a built-in is a good, competitive answer and should be accepted. It is still not true that the answer is *"unbeatable"*. It could certainly be *tied*, and then what would you do? Oh, look—and it already has been tied with an APL answer. Which goes back to it's just generally unsporting to accept an answer to a code-golf question the same day that you post the question.

Comment: The best solution in such cases is to forget about te accept feature, which isn't really relevant anyway here.

Comment: The test cases only have 1 digit numbers; my solution only works well on 1 digit numbers. Is there any problem?

Comment: I don't understand the test cases. [7, 4, 5] gets sorted to [4, 5, 7], so 7 is in the third position, 3 in the first, and 5 in the second. Shouldn't this result in [3, 1, 2]? Similarly for [2, 6, 1, 9, 1, 2, 3] gets sorted to [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 6, 9] and the result should be [3, 6, 1, 7, 2, 4, 5]? Can someone please help me understand where I am going wrong? I'd love to submit an answer but can't understand the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 byte

```
Ụ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///h7iX/D7c/alrj/v9/dLS5joKJjoJprA6XQrShjoKRjoIxmA1kmOkoAEUswSRc3CQ2FgA)

Comment: Heh that was too obvious...

Comment: APL deserved this one, +1 though for your speed.

Comment: @Zacharý I'm sure Jelly picked this one up from J, which in turn inherited it from APL.

Answer (score 11):

## Dyalog APL, 1 byte

```
⍋
```

Dyalog APL has a built in <strike>operator</strike> function (thank you Zacharý for clearing this up) to do this.

### Example

```
⍋11 2 4 15
    2 3 1 4  
{⍵[⍋⍵]}11 4 2 15
    2 4 11 15
```

Here I'm indexing into the list by the sorted indices to return the list in ascending order.

Comment: Oh, just to alert you to some confusing terminology, in APL, builtins like `⍋` are considered functions, while things like `¨⍨⍣.∘/\⌿⍀⌸⍤` are operators.

Comment: polyglot with BQN.

Answer (score 10):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>43</s> 42 bytes

`1`-indexed:

```hs
import Data.List
map snd.sort.(`zip`[1..])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7BCsIwEETv@Yo5thAD1ap48KRHhR6FWGzQRoNJDN2c/HhjKIKIe1jYecvM3BTde2uTceExRGxVVGJnKDKNNY7JqQDyF0EZiqJ7mtDJSoi2TLGnSPlHQi45ao55y/AZDllxTDlmP1oWFhyZrMb9x@vv1TLmlPHZPzfYn1CEwfgodIkxN73O2qorpclh0zRv)

`-1` byte thanks to @ØrjanJohansen!

Comment: Pointfree version saves one byte: ``map snd.sort.(`zip`[1..])``.

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 56 bytes

This solution is 0-indexed. This abuses the fact that `sorted()` creates a copy of the original list.

```python
l=input()
for k in sorted(l):a=l.index(k);print a;l[a]=0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8c2M6@gtERDkystv0ghWyEzT6E4v6gkNUUjR9Mq0TZHLzMvJbVCI1vTuqAoM69EIdE6Jzox1tbg//9oIx0FMx0FQx0FSzAJ5BrHAgA)

Comment: Why did you ungolf this?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Fixed, Rollback.

Answer (score 9):

## Javascript (ES6), 39 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to @powelles

This only works in browsers where `Array.prototype.sort` is stable.

```
a=>[...a.keys()].sort((b,c)=>a[b]-a[c])
```

1-indexed version (47 bytes):

```
a=>a.map((_,i)=>i+1).sort((b,c)=>a[b-1]-a[c-1])
```

**Example code snippet:**

```js
f=
a=>[...a.keys()].sort((b,c)=>a[b]-a[c])
console.log("7,4,5 => "+f([7,4,5]))
console.log("1,2,3 => "+f([1,2,3]))
console.log("2,6,1,9,1,2,3 => "+f([2,6,1,9,1,2,3]))
console.log("4 -> "+f([4]))
```

Comment: `[...a.keys()]` instead of `a.map((_,i)=>i)` will save you a couple of bytes.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 48 bytes

```python
lambda x:sorted(range(len(x)),key=x.__getitem__)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcdRCoMwDADQq@QzgTKYgjDBk2yjVBq1TNNSI9TTV9nPg5dOXaI0dRo@dXXb6B2Ufo9Z2WN2MjOuLFiIzI/PoTysnVmD8mYt1ZSDKEwYJB2KRPXdGOgMPA28/t5tvxc)

Comment: Nice, I got outgolfed >_<. I switched my answer to Python 3 such that I don't feel that bad

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Well, that's his job...

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Come on, you shouldn't feel bad for that! You made a full program, I made a function, and my approach is a bit different.

Comment: I don't feel bad, I knew this will appear (I personally hate the `__<blahblah>__` syntax). I will do some Jelly, I don't want to lose my training :)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Codegolf doesn't mean pretty syntax and formatting. ;)

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Those aren't news for me :) (I've been around for a while, I learnt that long ago)

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>27</s>  21 bytes

```perl6
*.pairs.sort(*.value)».key
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##ZZBBasMwEEX3OsVfFTuVBU4ch2ISfIAuuyiELIw9BVE3FpZsYkpOll0v5o7lhJBWC6GZ//5oZgy1dTp2ltCnqszE14CnsqkI23GhTKFbq2zTumCh@qLuKPy5qE8aRg/mjqzDFoEA9huJRGJ9wMOR2C8lVhLxQU5ULDHF/6mb4Cl@pWyRePH31cEUF1r7FMsbLySzI/lT8V6X9TAT04Bv3G0mTF0c8Ty3Xukey0x8NO11lmiHXB9N5yRyOhkqHVX45g@0jSoiUw@YlhPMUKhetWU0uLPvEeJbeoaU4Q2L8/gL)

```perl6
->\x{sort {x[$_]},^x}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##ZZDBaoNAEIbv@xT/oRRDR8HEGIok@AA99lAwphSdgmDj4m6CQXx2O64JIe0elp35v392ZjS3dTyeDOMcB0Wifi54LpqSsR393b7rTdNa9F329JkPdOiG0SGpZWOxhaeAbEOICOscD4eQLQkrQpjTRIWEKf5P3QRHySsWC@HV3VeHUFJo7VIib5wQzY7oT8V7XdEXiZpGe5duE6XrryNe5tbL6oxlor6b9jqLv0NaHfXJElLuNBeWS/TyQWX8klnXF0xr8WZoEbxVRlDvzn74CG/pGQq07FYN4y8)

Inspired by a [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136637/get-the-indices-of-an-array-after-sorting/136656#136656)

### Expanded:

```perl6
->    # pointy block lambda
  \x  # declare sigilless parameter
{
  sort
    { x[$_] },  # sort by the value in ｢x｣ at the given position
    ^x          # Range up-to the number of elements in ｢x｣
}
```

Answer (score 5):

## Bash + coreutils, 20

```bash
nl|sort -nk2|cut -f1
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Py@npji/qERBNy/bqCa5FMhIM/z/34jLjMuQyxKIjbiMAQ).

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 5 bytes

There is a builtin function for this.

```r
order
```

Comment: Standard rules is to provide a program of function. `order` is already a function, so you don't have to handle input using `scan()`. This would be 5 bytes.

Comment: `rank()` would save a byte

Comment: I am sure there was a `rank` answer by @JarkoDubbeldam, but I do not see it anymore.

Comment: Correct, it does not follow the spec so I deleted it.

Answer (score 4):

## [Swift 4](https://github.com/apple/swift), 82 bytes

```swift
func f(l:[Int]){var l=l;for k in l.sorted(){let a=l.index(of:k)!;print(a);l[a]=0}}
```

[Test Suite.](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/597d9e77c5cfd27e04c56f0e)

### Explanation

In Swift, `l.sorted()` creates a sorted copy of the original Array. We loop through the sorted elements in the list and after printing each item's index in the original Array with `let a=l.index(of:k)!;print(a)`, and then, in order to keep the correct indexes in the Array, we assign `l[a]` to `0`, because it does not affect our normal output.

---

Take note that this is 0-indexed, since it is a port of my Python solution. If you want it to be 1-indexed, replace `print(a)` with `print(a+1)` or [Try it online!](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/597da09cc5cfd27e04c56f0f).

Answer (score 4):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 17 bytes

```matlab
@(i)[~,y]=sort(i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQSNTM7pOpzLWtji/qATI@Z@YV6yRmVdQWqKhrq6p@T/aSEfBTEfBUEfBEkwCucaxAA)

Octave is like MATLAB but with inline assignment, making things possible that gives the folks at Mathworks HQ headaches. It doesn't matter what you call `y`, but you can't do without that dummy variable, as far as I know.

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 2 bytes

```
/:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/X98KhBXMFUwUTLmADEMFIwXj/2AuAA)

Zero-based indexing.

Comment: Was going to post this...

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 40 bytes

```ruby
->a{a.zip([*1..a.size]).sort.map &:last}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6xOlGvKrNAI1rLUE8vUa84syo1VlOvOL@oRC83sUBBzSonsbik9n@BQlp0tJGOgpmOgqGOgiWYBHKNY2P/AwA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org), 8 bytes

```
sortperm
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=nY8xTsMwGIXn-BRPmRzJRRTSlg6NWDlDlMFJ_7ZGqWvZjmDIJZhZulTiMhwgt8FJGiFg4x8s_e89f3r_--W5qZU8d5-7k4WC0rAkt7XS5HjCEEYKlNjAmVp5rgTiNk5YpLRpfJBzI60j_qT9MhX-5ih9dUjQw3wPI1kdBo3bmOe3s3WRxAIyKVhEr4YqT9v_QsoeIrV7IRsQY582Q0l7pS-N380ePtzJekP2OK5dFpHesshYpX2t-fWEDCMkHPUonSPrMVE3mEqy8HOknLu3fCWQCiwK_JgW-Z3AvcC8YPlcoF_-RiaD9eFlCAush_caD5GAWAxSsFeDkYZ4-ov1TSzGZl8)

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 2 bytes

```
&S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/Xy34//9oIx0FMx0FQx0FSzAJ5BrHAgA)

Input and output are implicit.

Answer (score 3):

## [MY](https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/my-language/src/5984ac62a269d7a763c1ef664f5b7d745b7f9390?at=master), 3 bytes

MY also has a builtin for this!

```
⎕⍋↵
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y638//9R39RHvd2P2rb@/x9tqGOkY6xjomMQCwA)

#### How?

Evaluated input, grade up, then output with a newline.

Indexed however you set the index, with `⌶`/`0x48`. (Can even be some weird integer like `-1` or `2`, the default is `1`).

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, 128 + 19 = 147 bytes

Based on Mr. Xcoder's [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136643). 0-based. Lambda takes input as an `Integer[]` and returns `Integer[]`. Byte count includes lambda expression and required import.

```java
import java.util.*;
```

```java
l->{Integer o[]=l.clone(),s[]=l.clone(),i=0;for(Arrays.sort(s);i<l.length;)l[o[i]=Arrays.asList(l).indexOf(s[i++])]=0;return o;}
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##VZBNS8NAEIbPya@Y465NFz9AkDQFL0JB8dBjyGFNtnHqdjbsTqql5LfHrUZLL8N8zzzvVu/13HWGts3HiLvOeYZtzKme0aqrPE27/s1iDbXVIcCLRoJjmnQe95oNBNYci@eJTU81oyP1NDmLFbFpjS@rDP7dJYR4yDQrarA2AYrRzpfHqQyurAqrauvICJmFiwiL63zjvHj0Xh@COq0RQea4sMoaavk9l7Z0JVbF1KHDMwYWViqkxny9bkQocTarZBU3ecO9J3D5MCYRNZlYJ6q9wwZ2kVis2SO1ZQXat0GeBEjWh8Bmp1zPKopBbOnvJ3a/7eKCUemuswdB5vMsAxxvM7jP4CaDhx8bw7tBSpmnyZAO4zc)

### Ungolfed lambda

```java
l -> {
    Integer
        o[] = l.clone(),
        s[] = l.clone(),
        i = 0
    ;
    for (Arrays.sort(s); i < l.length; )
        l[o[i] = Arrays.asList(l).indexOf(s[i++])] = 0;
    return o;
}
```

### Notes

I use `Integer[]` instead of `int[]` to allow use of [`Arrays.asList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-), which has no primitive versions. `Integer` is preferred to `Long` because values are used as array indices and would require casting.

This ended up being shorter than my best procedural-style `List` solution because of the cost of class and method names.

This also beat a solution I tried that streamed the inputs, mapped to *(value, index)* pairs, sorted on values, and mapped to indices, mostly because of the baggage needed to collect the stream.

### Acknowledgments

- -5 bytes thanks to *Nevay*

Comment: You don't need `j`: `l->{Integer o[]=l.clone(),s[]=l.clone(),i=0;for(Arrays.sort(s);i<l.length;l[o[i]=Arrays.asList(l).indexOf(s[i++])]=0);return o;}` (19+128 bytes).

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 8 bytes

```
arg-sort
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bczBCoJAEAbg@z7F3wMkmJZUDyBdukSn6DDIJNKybrMbZOKzb6t0EZzDMMP/8T@o8q2E6@V0Lg9w/Hqzqdgl/PFCDlbY@85KYzyeLIY1ajYspJsv@aY1DkelehTIscWA2azQY4MMKYZI0uleIP9AjXgXv/2cjiSL5WkMixjkE40bN2CpbVCBpF67Vny4R2jIWt0hcag0k4Qf)

0-indexed

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp, 82 bytes

```
(lambda(l)(loop as i in(sort(copy-seq l)'<)do(setf(elt l(print(position i l)))0)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcsxCsMwDEbhq2jLr6HQJlAo9DJO4oBAsdRIS07veviWB29TCe/o0HKue4Ey1MypBAlJQ9iV2MzvR9QfKU9f3g1R80DVJIVf0hJuISnWxqTM/Bz6hJne9KLPMNMyyh8)

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB / [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 29 bytes

```matlab
[~,y]=sort(input(''));disp(y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/uk6nMta2OL@oRCMzr6C0RENdXVPTOiWzuECjUhMobaSjYKajYKijYAkmgVzjWAA)

Comment: While your answer is perfect MATLAB, you can actually [do inline assignment in anonymous functions in Octave](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136679/32352).

Comment: Good one! I knew about in-line assignment, but I didn't know you could output directly like that

Comment: To be honest, me neither. I started with something like `@(X)([~,y]=sort(X))`, and while I was looking of a way to get `y` from this, I realized `y` was actually the return value from the assignment, and closer inspection revealed that brackets weren't even needed. MATLAB likes everything explicit; Octave is happy when it's unambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

### Clojure, 39 bytes

```
#(map key(sort-by val(zipmap(range)%)))
```

Comment: Translated to Perl 6 `{map *.key,(sort *.value,(0..* Z=> @_))}`

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 12 bytes

```
{ee{1=}$0f=}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1fWPe/OjW12tC2VsUgzbb2f13C/2gjBTMFQwVLIDZSMI4FAA)

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 69 bytes

0-indexed. Works for lists containing up to 65,536 elements.

```js
a=>[...a=a.map((n,i)=>n<<16|i)].sort((a,b)=>a-b).map(n=>a.indexOf(n))
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

a=>[...a=a.map((n,i)=>n<<16|i)].sort((a,b)=>a-b).map(n=>a.indexOf(n))

console.log(JSON.stringify(f([7, 4, 5])))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([1, 2, 3])))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([2, 6, 1, 9, 1, 2, 3])))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([4])))
```

Comment: Can you change `n=>a.indexOf(n)` to just `a.indexOf`?

Comment: @Zacharý Unfortunately not. A method of an instanced object cannot be used as a callback.

Comment: @Zacharý Even worse is that `Array#map` passes 3 arguments to the callback function, and `Array#indexOf` expects 2, so it will give undesirable results.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) with [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/), <s>38</s> 26 bytes

*12 bytes saved thanks to [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king) (no need to give the function a name)*

```python
import numpy
numpy.argsort
```

Output is 0-based.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRCGvNLegkgtM6iUWpRcDxf6nKdgqoIhwFRRl5pVopGlEG@komOkoGOooWIJJINc4VlPzPwA)

Comment: The function could just be `numpy.argsort` without the lambda part

Comment: @JoKing Thanks for the suggestion. I wrote it that way because with just `numpy.argsort;import numpy` I get an error (`numpy` has not been imported yet), and with `import numpy;numpy.argsort` I need to move `f=` to the code part. Do you know that the standard procedure is in these cases? Move the `f=` and not count it?

Comment: Yeah, I guess. Maybe just redefine `f=numpy.argsort` in the footer

Comment: @JoKing Good idea. Done. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 52 bytes

0-indexed. Based on [Bruce Forte's Haskell answer here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136639/47581) and [G B's Ruby answer here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136765/47581).

```python
lambda l:list(zip(*sorted(zip(l,range(len(l))))))[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcZNCoAgEEDhq7QcYzZlPxB0knJhaCVMJjqburyFb/O@8PB5e5n3ec2kr83oiiZyieF1Aep0R7ammDBqf1gg64FEaWlUDtF5hh0WiR1K7LEtb3DA8XevhMgf)

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>10</s> 7 bytes

This is a direct port of my [Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136639/48198), also `1`-indexed:

```
m→O`z,N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/dR2yT/hCodv////0cb6ZjpGOpYArGRjnEsAA)

#### Ungolfed/Explained

```
Code        Description               Example
         -- implicit input            [2,6,1]
      N  -- natural numbers           [1,2,3,..]
   `z,   -- zip, but keep input left  [(2,1),(6,2),(1,3)]
  O      -- sort                      [(1,3),(2,1),(6,2)]
m→       -- keep only indices         [3,1,2]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 72 bytes

```java
l->l.stream().sorted().map(i->{int j=l.indexOf(i);l.set(j,0);return j;})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVLLTsMwEDzHX7FHG6UWbwRpI3FBqgTiwBFxMIlTOU2cyHZKS9VvD5tHaVpaLn7szs6Ox5uKhRgVpdRpPK9VXhbGQYoxXjmV8bOA/IkllY6cKjR/6g9HMNYZKXL@1m4BIWX1makIokxYCy9CabImXh@0TjjcFoWKIccUxSqlZ@8fIMzMMuIh1Csx5GiEdE4@GiNWz8o6eufDtQ83jAUnIZc@3Ppw4cN9u@L16j/4ELIhHmlgC0RsVf4ix1Pt5EyaEA4pkJZzDqpXfqRCwAS0/BqQhbTVlBQGmnpYwgMSeIKLOKbLNmekq4wGcUJYa1/3pmMdezFvK@tkzovK8Rab6Q5tuSs626lV33KqY7mkgmG0TVM2MGTv17of3jXaVR9RMe9VbAdnvJf2D8lCSNCoOhuF24GijFscNBnjIRclVaNw3diVTjKumq6vCVUsQLh0NPXPWdC7lgYbVg9cTLgoy2xF592zNqT@AQ)

Takes a `List<Integer>`, returns a `Stream<Integer>` containing the results.

We get a Stream based off the initial list, sort it, then map each number to it's index in the list. In order to accommodate duplicate elements, we set the original element in the list to `0`.

Answer (score 2):

## SmileBASIC, 67 bytes

```
DEF I(A)DIM B[0]FOR I=1TO LEN(A)PUSH B,I
NEXT
SORT A,B
RETURN B
END
```

Very simple, all it does is generate a list of numbers from 1 to (length of array) and sort this by the same order as the input.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 1 byte

```
⇧
```

[Try It Online!](https://vyxapedia.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCLih6ciLCIiLCIiLCJbMiwgNiwgMSwgOSwgMSwgMiwgM10iXQ==)

0-indexed

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 1 [byte](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ƙ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#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)

Same as the other golflangs - built-in for "grade up".

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), 27 bytes

Yields a 1-indexed result.

```
f(l)=sort([1...l.length],l)
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lgdaf2d1vg?nographpaper)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
ā<Σè
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//SKPNucWHV/z/H22ko2Cmo2Coo2AJJoFc41gA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 16 bytes

```
a->vecsort(a,,1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYgxCoAwEAS/slglcCnUqFjoR0KKQ1QE0SOK4OtjFGx2Z0Y4LGaWOKFDZNNf43Ds4VRMlOvIIuutGKaHhGVLGdkrGSbFWhOcawiWUPnEOaEglC@mrwkptN/@2Xqv4wM)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 54 bytes

```php
<?php function i($a){asort($a);return array_keys($a);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go0AhrTQvuSQzP08hU0MlUbM6sTi/qATEsi5KLSktylNILCpKrIzPTq0sBovW/lcpSS0u8cwrKC1RsFWINtJRMNNRMNRRsASTQK5xrDUXF1dBUWZeSXyRBtBUuHpNTev/AA)

This is zero-indexed. Simply sorts the array and returns the keys.

Comment: The `<?php` tag is unnecessary for a function. 48 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 21 bytes

(0-indexed)

```
puts [lsort -indi $L]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@Z@Tm1ig4KNQXW2uYKJgWqtQbahgpGAMpI0UzBQMFSwVYHyTWiDxv6C0pFghOqc4v6hEQTczLyVTQcUn9n/tfwA)

Comment: The test cases only have 1 digit numbers; my solution only works well on 1 digit numbers.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 34 bytes

```
->a{(0...a.size).sort_by{|i|a[i]}}
```

0-indexed, 1-indexing requires one more net byte:

```
->a{(1..a.size).sort_by{|i|a[i-1]}}
```

Also, a slightly golfed version of [G B's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136765/6828) is 37 bytes:

```
->a{a.each_with_index.sort.map &:pop}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org),  <s>44</s>  34 bytes

<sup>not today, crossed out 44</sup>

```
{l->(1..l.size).sortedBy{l[it-1]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@1@WmKOQZqWg4ZNZXGLjmVdip6mga6cA5ynY/q/O0bXTMNTTy9ErzqxK1dQrzi8qSU1xqqzOic4s0TWMra39n1aap5CbmJmnoalQzaUABAVFmXklOXkaaRo5QJP80zTMdRRMdBRMNTU1uWr/AwA)

1-indexed because that's what the examples give. A 0-indexed version looks like this for 30 bytes:

```
{l->l.indices.sortedBy{l[it]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, <s>6</s> 5 bytes

0-indexed

```
ð ñ@v
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=8CDxQHY=&input=WzIsIDYsIDEsIDksIDEsIDIsIDNd)

---

#### Alternative, 6 bytes

```
í ñÎmÌ
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=7SDxzm3M&input=WzIsIDYsIDEsIDksIDEsIDIsIDNd)