# Find a Similar Number

Tags: code-golf, string, number

We consider two integers to be *similar* if, when written in decimal, have the same length, and if we compare characters in any two positions for both decimal strings, the comparison results (less, equal or greater) must be the same in both strings.

Formally, for two number that can be written as decimal strings \$a_1a_2\cdots a_n\$, \$b_1b_2\cdots b_m\$, they're *similar* if and only if \$n=m\$ and \$a_i<a_j\ \leftrightarrow b_i<b_j\$ (\$\leftrightarrow\$ means if and only if) for all \$ i,j \in [1,n]\$.

For example, 2131 and 8090 are *similar*. 1234 and 1111, 1234 and 4321 are **not** *similar*.

## The challenge

For a given positive integer, find a different non-negative integer *similar* to it. You can assume at least one such integer exists.

- Your implementation shouldn't be too inefficient. It must be at least able to pass the samples in around one hour on an average computer. (If it doesn't end in a few seconds, consider providing a screenshot running it)
- Your code can take the input and output as integers, strings or lists of digits. Standard loopholes are forbidden.

Since this is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code in bytes wins!

## Examples

It's (quite) possible to have different outputs on these inputs as long as inputs and outputs are different and *similar*.

```
1 - 0
3 - 9
9 - 1
19 - 23
191 - 121
1111 - 2222 (0 is not considered valid)
2020 - 9393
2842 - 1321
97892 - 31230
113582 - 113452
444615491 - 666807690
87654321000 - 98765432111
98765432111 - 87654321000
526704219279 - 536714329379
99887766553210 - 88776655443210
```

Sample inputs as a list:

```
1,3,9,19,191,1111,2020,2842,97892,113582,444615491,87654321000,98765432111,526704219279,99887766553210
```

Comment: Looks like you posted the challenge only *4 hours* after you posted it to the sandbox. It's way too short to get a meaningful feedback. It is recommended to keep it in the sandbox for at least 3 days.

Comment: Sorry, I'll keep that in mind next time. Thanks. @Bubbler

Comment: Related: [Imitate an ordering](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/62587/20260)

Comment: The sample is updated, [python tester for sample, check if you're not sure of definition](https://tio.run/##dVBda8IwFH3vr7iyh7RwlST2K2P1Rba9TRBhD@JDqqkWalpjC@2vd0mdYwwWAsnJOeee3NsM7anW89vtoAoofB08e2BU2xkNesrgqam6I5QahrozcJbHcg9Fp/dtWWs4KaMmo/FanstKGr/BiyvQ45BdWwsDdMcl8KAsoFLa74NJ5s7ByR5Bb7K6Kg@K2oB0WUbqo/Ip3g2j0nH5P5yr7fdbuXvpt/nOBviDA4MDI/8n5xttTKe8NtsynKNA5jZDZhdyyinyNOQoklRw@ziPUo5hGMYsCq0qTeIonHNGKUXxANYY8TihIWeCJwKFSNMkieMocsqd99Neaz@VZ6Vu/cKXgZ1NYxyQSKYLgjmS2WxGUOlDRoDcR5cvMgpSH0BOsny8PCYuMR@bvNcgy9V6/brcOJuyzf5iPterj3cS3L4A)

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the second condition (the comparison results) when at leas one of ``m`` or ``n`` is ``1``.

Comment: Doesn't really matter for single-digit numbers. They're all similar. @mappo

Comment: Does this definition not mean that a number is similar to itself?

Comment: Yes, but it's explicitly stated that you should output a *different* similar number. @retnikt

Comment: What about an input like `123456789`? I believe there is no number that is both similar to and different from it, so what should we output?

Comment: you're apparently not the first one asking this. *You can assume at least one such integer exists.* @Seb

Answer (score 15):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>58</s> 52 bytes

```python
lambda n:[9-(9in n)-sum(x>d for x in{*n})for d in n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVDJTsMwEL37K4ZycYCixM3mivTID8Ct9OA2DrjE08hxpKKq3148CYsQkaX4LTNvPN2Hfzvg4tJUL5dW2W2tAJdrOefSIGA07wfLj6samoODIxg83eA5IlADGTaXa9i96d07mAYQFNZgQTkNvbGmVQ62g4faNI126AEHu9VuyWrdTFUc72y0ZDBWV5WF0LjVyDG6qugfRHDaDw7hUbW9npxWHbm9xWglyW8Njugh/uelOQ3N6RS@aj51HvMmbf9Xs9/amMJxbTYPuN5vwjDcErAE/qV8wWc3aMaM7Q7OQ//RM0poDWoKCfi@97VBCsAn76AatUA60/GI2ED5oWs1N@j5Lhon3I1bDn5y2B9HQ@8gZuo0m93vD7QG1fHQMOyUxM5Ro2Z2ovozzFdwsuNtffpd/nkziy4JWzDJEjoJS8LHRCxiJspUMFmUUgRykZWCpWmaJ1kaXGWRZ@lCJHEcM/kNQmEm8iJORSJFIZmUZVkUeZ5l5PwE)

**Input**: The number `n`, as a list of digits.
**Output**: A similar number, as a list of digits.

*-6 bytes thanks to @xnor!*

**How**:
Reverses the list of unique digits, then maps them to `9,8,7,...` or `8,7,6,...` depending on whether `n` contains the digit 9 or not.
For example:

```python
               | n = 1827 | n = 7899
Reverse unique |   8721   |   987
Maps to        |   9876   |   876
Results        | m = 6978 | m = 6788
```

#### Old solution

#### [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 80 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,i=9:(i in n)^(i-1in n)and[[d,d^i^~-i][i-2<d<=i]for d in n]or f(n,i-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzBboMwEETv@xUWJ1uCyDY2tqPQH0Eg0bhRtgoGAZdc@ut0jdRaPuzMvJnlvT/nVB/Ho32N02ccWSqxDVeODBNLYuBYqfMaU@y6WMYBh58K@w4rfYu3FvvHvLJ40j1dD04DlRIHTsu87mx7b5CJF6avDJG@bHvEdAXGNtaeATkrLlyQlcjqMO38Llju3c9ST8mYMk774l8UxeV7xsSnceE0UZIrcrqseWEri@qjOM1DQQ0BVP4KFD3QUkvQ3mgIzgdNZm29BmNMo6whyrvGmlorKSWEP0FFqxsnjVZBuwAheO9c01ibyV8)

**Input**: The number `n`, as a list of digits.
**Output**: A similar number, as a list of digits.

*-1 byte thanks to @KevinCruijssen!*

**How**
The solution tries to find a pair of consecutive digits \$(i-1,i)\$ such that one digit appears in \$n\$, and the other doesn't. It then replaces all occurrences of one digit with the other.
The pair of digits are searched from \$(8,9)\$ downward, in order to discourage replacing 1 with 0.

Comment: I like your 50-byter, but I'm afraid it's incorrect for `n=9` and `n=98765432111`. You're supposed to find a different number.

Comment: Fixed, but at the cost of 9 bytes. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @SurculoseSputum I also wrote out a pretty similar solution before finding it didn't work on those test cases.

Comment: @SurculoseSputum Glad you managed to fix it. And your approach inspired a -6 golf on my own answer. :)

Comment: Shorter sorted indexing: [TIO](https://tio.run/##ZVDJTsMwEL37K4ZycYCixM3mivTID8Ct9OA2DrjE08hxpKKq3148CYsQkaX4LTNvPN2Hfzvg4tJUL5dW2W2tAJdrOefSIGA07wfLj6samoODIxg83eA5IlADGTaXa9i96d07mAYQFNZgQTkNvbGmVQ62g4faNI126AEHu9VuyWrdTFUc72y0ZDBWV5WF0LjVyDG6qugfRHDaDw7hUbW9npxWHbm9xWglyW8Njugh/uelOQ3N6RS@aj51HvMmbf9Xs9/amMJxbTYPuN5vwjDcErAE/qV8wWc3aMaM7Q7OQ//RM0poDWoKCfi@97VBCsAn76AatUA60/GI2ED5oWs1N@j5Lhon3I1bDn5y2B9HQ@8gZuo0m93vD7QG1fHQMOyUxM5Ro2Z2ovozzFdwsuNtffpd/nkziy4JWzDJEjoJS8LHRCxiJspUMFmUUgRykZWCpWmaJ1kaXGWRZ@lCJHEcM/kNQmEm8iJORSJFIZmUZVkUeZ5l5PwE "Python 3 – Try It Online"). Also more testing.

Comment: Nice! I am afraid it fails for `50213456789`.

Comment: @Master_ex I don't think `50213456789` is a valid input, since there is no other number similar to it.

Comment: @SurculoseSputum Maybe I am missing something. Isn't in that case `40213456789` for example similar?

Comment: The 1st and 6th leftmost digits (1-indexed) are 54 vs 44, which doesn't satisfy the requirement (4<5 iff 4<4).

Comment: @SurculoseSputum Thank you, I missed this part.

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript (ES6), 55 bytes

I/O format: list of digits.

```javascript
a=>a.map(d=>d-=-!/9/.test(a)|!a.includes(d-=d>(a<'2')))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU/LbsMgELz3K5wTIMUEME@1@NZrfyDKgRqcOnJMZJye@u8uUHWl2dfM7mpv7tulYZ0eW7tEH/bR7s72Dt/dA3rb@9a2h5M54S2kDTr0c3B4Wob56UOCmfQ9dG@AAYTQ/noGFBxBl2Ey6J8rLZotB0YYKUFzVjRKG1bJTuiScM4lFbxOaCUF7xglpEyY/7KuEUwqwhk1TJUTxmitlJRCFD24vOAxru9u@IKpsX0zxCXFOeA5XmE6NiM8Y4zTpT748bx/hhUhfIvTAkH94hc)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>                // a[] = input array of digits
  a.map(d =>        // for each digit d in a[]:
    d -=            //   update d:
      -!/9/.test(a) //     if a[] doesn't include any 9, increment d
      |             //     (this does d = d - (-1 | whatever) = d - (-1) = d + 1)
                    //     otherwise, decrement d if:
      !a.includes(  //     - a[] does not include d - 1
        d -= d >    //     - and d is greater than 0 if the leading digit is not 1,
          (a < '2') //       or greater than 1 otherwise (so that it doesn't result
      )             //       in a leading zero)
  )                 // end of map()
```

Comment: I guess your code is not working on input `191`?

Comment: @newbie Thanks for reporting this. Now fixed. I think `191` should be added to the test cases.

Comment: Good idea, added. Updated sample tester too. @Arnauld

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>20</s> <s>16</s> 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
êRāTα:DIQ-
```

-6 bytes after being inspired by [*@SurculoseSputum* partially incorrect approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/203194/2).

I/O as a list of digits.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8KqgI40h5zZauXgG6v7/H22pY6FjrmOmY6pjomOsY6RjoGMQCwA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWWwy6GV/w@vCjrSGHJuo5XLoXWBuv@9dP5HG@oY61jqGIKQoY4hEOgYGRgZ6BhZmBjpWJpbWBoBBY1NLYx0TExMzAxNTYCqLMzNTE2MjQwNDAx0LKEcJCbIDFMjM3MDEyNDSyNzSx1LSwsLc3MzM1NTkKZYAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
ê          # Sort and uniquify the digits in the (implicit) input-list
           #  i.e. [2,8,4,2] → [2,4,8]
 R         # And reverse it
           #  → [8,4,2]
  ā        # Push a list in the range [1, length] (without popping)
           #  → [1,2,3]
   Tα      # Take the absolute difference with 10
           #  → [9,8,7]
     :     # Replace in the (implicit) input-list the sorted unique digits with [9,8,...]
           #  → [7,9,8,7]
      D    # Duplicate it
       IQ  # Check whether it's equal to the input-list (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
           #  → 0 (falsey)
         - # Subtract that from each digit
           #  → [7,9,8,7]
           # (after which the resulting list is output implicitly)
```

---

**Original <s>20</s> 16 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) approach:**

```
∞IK.Δ‚εSæ2ùÆ.±}Ë
```

-4 bytes thanks to *@petStorm*.

I/O as regular integers.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9vc2FiaWX//@KInklLLs6U4oCazrVTw6Yyw7nDhi7CsX3Di///Mjg0Mg) or [verify the smaller test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWXo/0cd8yq99c5NiXjUMOvc1uDDy4wO7zzcpndoY@3h7v@1Ov@jDXWMdSx1DEHIUMcQCHSMDIwMdIwsTIx0LM0tLI1iAQ) (larger ones time out).

**Explanation:**

```python
∞              # Push an infinite list of positive integers: [1,2,3,...]
 IK            # Remove the input-integer itself from the list
.Δ             # Then find the first value in this list which is truthy for:
  ‚            #  Pair the current value with the (implicit) input-integer
               #   i.e. input=2842 and y=1321 → [2842,1321]
   ε           #  Map both to:
    S          #   Convert them to a list of digits
               #    → [[2,8,4,2],[1,3,2,1]]
     æ         #   Take the powerset of this list of digits
      2ù       #   Only leave the pairs
               #    → [[[2,8],[2,4],[2,2],[8,4],[8,2],[4,2]],
               #       [[1,3],[1,2],[1,1],[3,2],[3,1],[2,1]]]
        Æ      #   Reduce each inner pair by subtracting
               #    → [[-6,-2,0,4,6,2],
               #       [-2,-1,0,1,2,1]]
         .±    #   Take the signum of each (-1 if a<0; 0 if a==0; 1 if a>0)
               #    → [[-1,-1,0,1,1,1],
               #       [-1,-1,0,1,1,1]]
           }Ë  #  After the inner map: check if the pair of lists are the same
               #   → 1 (truthy)
               # (after we've found our value, it is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: I got an incomplete [idea](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9vc2FiaWX//@KAms61w6Yyw7nOtS5TfX3Di///Mjg0MgoxMzIx) over here. If you can complete it it'd be great.

Comment: @petStorm Ah, nice approach with the powerset. :) Here is a possible way to fix it for 17 bytes: [``∞IK.Δ‚εæ2ùε`.S}}Ë``](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9vc2FiaWX//@KInklLLs6U4oCazrXDpjLDuc61YC5TfX3Di///Mjg0Mg) ([test suite](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWXo/0cd8yq99c5NiXjUMOvc1sPLjA7vPLc1QS@4tvZw9/9anf/RhjrGOpY6hiBkqGMIBDpGBkYGOkYWJkY6luYWlkaxAA)).

Comment: @petStorm 16 bytes actually: `∞IK.Δ‚εSæ2ùÆ.±}Ë` ([test suite](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWXo/0cd8yq99c5NiXjUMOvc1uDDy4wO7zzcpndoY@3h7v@1Ov@jDXWMdSx1DEHIUMcQCHSMDIwMdIwsTIx0LM0tLI1iAQ)).

Comment: To make it clear: I won't accept answers not passing the samples in decent time. But still, well done :)

Comment: @newbie Golfed 6 bytes while making it faster at the same time. ;) Still have to check if it 100% covers all possible test cases though. If you can think of any test case where this might fail for, let me know.

Comment: Hmm... `987654320`? @KevinCruijssen

Comment: @newbie Yeah, just saw that myself and was actually updating my answer. Fixed ;)

Answer (score 4):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 27 bytes

```
{((9-9=|/x)-!#?x)(?x@>x)?x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TUxBDsIwDPtKEJNoJcqaNG0TEJTX7LID10rb3l5aiQOWD7YTe3WftbXlvhmjTp/7XK07nUu1ptT3q9pSj7aZ@rhd52kxU7@y2OOCEEABBxGwA8iTBxIm0CxKPQxRCJg5YeT@JTlFDoTee9Cf@ZNjI1LKngmVsoKqSM4pxThK7Qs)

Takes the input as a list ot digits.

Inspired by [Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203193/75681) and [Surculose Sputum's Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203194/75681) solutions - please don't forget to upvote them!

Comment: Nice Galen.  What resources have you been using for learning K?

Comment: @Jonah Mostly [oK](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok). Also you can always chat in th [k-tree room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90748/the-k-tree)

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>24</s> 19 bytes

```
⭆θ⁻⁺⁸¬№θ9ＬΦγ∧›λι№θλ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCO4BEil@yYWaBTqKPhm5pUWawTkAAkLHQW//BIN5/xSoCKglJKlkqampo6CT2peekmGhltmTklqkUa6joJjXoqGe1FqIoibo6OQCVQD15SjCQHW//8bWhr@1y3LAQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Now based on @SurculoseSputum's newer answer. Explanation:

```
 θ                  Input as a string
⭆                   Map over characters and join
       θ            Input as a string
      № 9           Count `9`s
     ¬              Logical Not (i.e. does not contain `9`)
   ⁺⁸               Add `8`
          Φγ        Filter on printable ASCII
              λ     ASCII character
             ›      Greater than
               ι    Input character
            ∧       Logical And
                  λ ASCII character
                №θ  Occurs in input
         Ｌ          Length of matches
  ⁻                 Subtract from the `8` or `9`
                    Implicitly print
```

Previous 24-byte version based on @SurculoseSputum's older answer:

```
≔⌈Φχ¬№θＩιη⪫⪪θ⎇⁼η⁹⌈θＩ⊕ηＩη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzNCgIhFIX3PYXLKxhku5hVDAUFRVAvICZ5Qa/5F/X0NiN1VodzPj5tVdJBuda2OeOD4KTe6KuHPbpiEsiVYOdQYAyVCkTBRpULIJ8jmOXD4pJweo4BCa5Phx26mUQqfWAXq3IZrGCbif6rI/9pDqST8YaKuYPtwj7PdWhNrmVbvtwX) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⌈Φχ¬№θＩιη
```

Find the highest digit not present in the input number.

```
⎇⁼η⁹⌈θＩ⊕η
```

If that digit is less than 9 then increment it (which will give a digit in the input number) otherwise take the highest digit of the input number.

```
⪫⪪θ...Ｉη
```

Replace the digit from the input number with the digit not in the input number.

Answer (score 3):

## [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/A-ee/w/wiki/Code-Page)

Port of the 10-byte 05AB1E answer.

```
♥f<~|J▄5sO#o═╥
```

Uncompressed:

```
 oFU_:kkT-zrZ:a=-
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), 143 bytes

Port of Surculose Sputum's Python answer.

```erlang
u([])->[];u([H|T])->[H]++u([A||A<-T,A/=H]).
i(X)->case X of true->1;_->0end.
f(A)->[9-i(lists:member(9,A))-lists:sum([i(X>D)||X<-u(A)])||D<-A].
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7NCoMwEITvPkWOCWattb3400DAgw/gQZBQbBtLwJ@SKL3k3e3aXruwMLMfM6y2Qzc9Qbu7Na9lC7aVtoqBaFWOqvL111QqDNFK72UBNZeHS6VYFBjaIL13TpOGzD1Z7KpBHPMriFhPjyjoqdzjKRg6GLe4bNTjTVuacskY/E5uHWmLTaJk3jcFrJhRKMsCpIq2sTPT/hIBERAcM2dvaxZNe9omPOa4ijH@h534mSfIou0D)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 79 bytes

Port of @SurculoseSputum answer

```
#/.MapThread[Rule,{a=Union@#,Range[0,9][[-Tr[1^a]-(d=Boole[Max@a>8]);;-1-d]]}]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5tS8MwHMS/SllhKPzrkjSPjI4iIvhiIGO@ChGCDVlgTSVGEMY@e8xAj3tzx@/gZptPbrY5fNjih9JuHvb283hKzk768H12cLHDWwxLHFs42OidRqCM1t0xafxuTXc3DY/LcnZ6b39Gu5PmfrvtcDcZczXr8ppCzI1uYdV0u2YFz2mZn4IP@Wv0@iVm5136y60x6814wdCDAnwzBlwFBBEERFICSkhFatkzSYBSyjGjlZKCM9oTjFD99h/qkBEuECVYEaFAKSmF4JyxG3kt5Rc)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>29</sup> <sup>24</sup> 16 bytes

```
9-9&e.+\:~@~.i.]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVJNT8MwDL3nV1gc9gUNzbquH2LSNCROiAMXLiC0dWlWtLVo7U5I/evFcemaAELUiuo82y/Oi9@aCz5UsIhhCFfgQozL4XD7eH/XRE40kPzyOa6XNc/4SzNm5fogX8tMLTg48WB0c12PGXtYccgL2Mv1NssVEgBkaQpJcXgvgb6sgmS3zpXcwkSnCpelSDFy69j9UGPKmcCoYweEcOvwpRNrX28EOFgGkiPQHvkkoZJlBZui2sE2O8qkyoq8ZEwmuwJS7KPzorMnzt4UPAOdWpHW@mqPVp/tWfke1XvGeYJyZuAbLHOyELMC/EdWdyFhPla0zMJg/x5zybqoj@gcM8RXXPcZGPcNqT6gs31i6XnYT1G8XyWzfWFdU1jCubT6fYjHmUIGiEQG0grlI9pjM7I5RnS70b@l@FtG/RRaKJc6EtSFKVRE9bZYvVB63FanzWYvj1CelMKxw1Fj5vzge/cqah0Eaz4B)

*-8 thanks to FrownyFrog!*

*Thanks to Bubbler for catching some bugs.  All are now fixed.*

Inspired by Surculose's [sweet answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203194/15469), be sure to upvote him.

Comment: Nice! [`0<<./` -> `0&e.` for 22 bytes ?](https://tio.run/##bVHBasMwDL37K8QGbQOLa8dJHIcVBoOddtp5PZW03S47rLdCfj2V5MjxRhGKI70nvRfne3rQ6xPseljDExjoMUsNrx/vb9Nm248vo/7S@@L6@IlvpVkNeirUZfi97DSU/WrzvB0LdcSCenBSajicf8ACwBHTQKzdXIe5DnNtQfjSqZC79GziVRk3hvBjRKxCRUpRc5yCdVDjUza6bGcAj2hIqGNFl/xb5jfIWeapU2NPtGuOFvsNnov3lqPDXR7PkHZ2XBM3OjEc4vw/ajOv97A4d39nnCOnLeKGb8Hy1/p07w1OEGrnWbo3n/0vUqXtnr@mYX5UEOW/aJ15UGq6AQ)

Comment: Sorry for not checking it. I'm glad you fixed it!

Comment: `9-9&e.+\:~@~.i.]`

Comment: Impressive!  Thanks for finding this.  Something about it was bugging me.  Now I know why.

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + Unix utilities, <s>77</s> 74 bytes

```bash
tee t|tr "`rs -T|sort -ur|xargs`" "`grep -q 9 t;seq $[8+$?] -1 0|xargs`"<t
```

[Try the test suite online!](https://tio.run/##XU9Na8MwDL3rVzxMbiVbPposoVl32k6FXXYbg3qJSQZt09ou6yH/3ZPCwmAIWdLTe3r4U7shtNpje7Zjb/URTaOeX19U8MbAT95C7a1D/Da50XrEVzvdtO3dXvGit@aM@IIafuPMBdF7tYqePhCnSBZa4wPfI2qH49jhurrh14noe/g6GFijO@wI6EZ@ANMOI@ITVLTD4xbqD2Rgwt39ohfFyYSUcqopxZxI@Z2DMiTg5FphjYxqPHBXcyf7HAVPGa0hUTJScBV9xbxynnLW808kWP0fF4@Cu5LxRBwg/hlPNbOFLwrRiKpYrlH4AQ)

Input is a list of integers on stdin (space-separated digits).

Output is in the same format, on stdout.

This is an implementation of [Surculose Sputum's nice method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203194/59825): List the unique digits that appear in the input, sort them in decreasing order, and then replace them in the original input either with \$8, 7, 6, \dots\$ (if \$9\$ appears in the input) or with \$9, 8, 7, \dots\$ (if \$9\$ does not appear in the input).

Answer (score -1):

This is a port of [@Surculose Sputum's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203194/78264) in APL2.

```
U←((A⍳A)=⍳⍴A)/A←,A
((9∊A)⌽⌽⍳10)[U[⍒U]⍳A]
```

It presupposes that `A` is a vector of numbers and that `⎕IO=0`